# Creating Encodable class by injecting class conforming only to Encodable protocol

Tags: swift, encode, encodable

I am building network module which uses `Body` class that will be encoded to serve as body of url request. I want to init `Body` with any class that is conforming to Encodable protocol, in my case it is `MyDevice` class conforming to `DeviceEncodable`, which is protocol defining everything that my url request needs.  The`MyDevice` class is already inheriting from another class called `SpecialClass`, therefore I can only conform it to protocol since swift does not allow inheritance from more than one class. The problem is that when I initialize `Body` with `DeviceEncodable` I get the Error "Type 'Body' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'" I get it that it is because `DeviceEncodable` can be class but also some another protocol conforming to it. What is the correct solution to use `DeviceEncodable`  as a property in `Body` function so it will be encoded properly and without need to inherit ? Here is Samble code:

```
    class Body: Encodable {
    let device: DeviceEncodable
    init(_ deviceInfo: DeviceEncodable) {
        self.device = deviceInfo
    }
}

protocol DeviceEncodable: AnyObject, Encodable  {
    var someSpecialProperty: String {get}
}

class MyDevice: SpecialClass, DeviceEncodable {
    var someSpecialProperty: String = "special"
}

class SpecialClass {
    var someOtherProperty: String = "other"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot encode `device` because `device` must be a concrete type which conforms to `Encodable`. Possible solutions are an associated type of the protocol constrained to `Encodable` or a generic, something like

```
class Body<T : Encodable> : Encodable {
    let device: T

    init(_ deviceInfo: T) {
        self.device = deviceInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Generic pretty much solves the problem.